Chromote issue when webscraping in R (rvest)
I am trying to webscrape the following page using code that someone from this community had written for me several months ago
https://www.nba.com/stats/players/passing?DateFrom=10%2F22%2F2024&DateTo=10%2F22%2F2024
The purpose of the code is to scrape each day from the link above one by one. However it looks like the first line of the nba function below does not have the URL formatted correctly. As a test I tried using the exact URL but got the following error.
url=paste0("https://www.nba.com/stats/players/passing?DateFrom=10%2F22%2F2024&DateTo=10%2F22%2F2024")
a = read_html_live(url)

Error in `with_random_port()`:
! Cannot find an available port. Please try again.
Caused by error in `startup()`:
! Failed to start chrome. Error:

I found the following which says the issue has been fixed in a chromote update but not sure why I am getting this issue?
https://github.com/tidyverse/rvest/issues/421
Also noting that this code was originally written at the end of the 23-24 season and the code worked correctly so something appears to have changed since then and the beginning of the 24-25 season
Full code is below
### Setup chromote which is used by rvest (path to MS Edge is used here)
Sys.setenv(
  CHROMOTE_CHROME = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe"
)

### Load the packages
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

### Declare columns names.
### They'll be used to fix the table returned by rvest later
colnames = c(
  "PLAYER",
  "TEAM",
  "GP",
  "W",
  "L",
  "MIN",
  "PassesMade",
  "PassesReceived",
  "AST",
  "SecondaryAST",
  "PotentialAST",
  "AST_PTSCreated",
  "ASTAdj",
  "AST_ToPass%",
  "AST_ToPass%_Adj",
  "dummy"
)

### Get the dates of every match of the regular season
### We use basketball-reference.com here
calendrier=read_html("https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2025_games.html")

### The regular season starts in october and ends in april
### We get the url of each month
urls=calendrier %>% html_elements(xpath = '//div[@class="filter"]//a') %>% html_attr("href")
season=paste0("https://www.basketball-reference.com",urls[1:7])

### Function to get the date from each url
ext_dates = function(x) {
  a = read_html(x)
  b = a %>%
    html_element(xpath = "//table") %>%
    html_table %>% select(Date,Notes)
}

### We apply the function for each page (month)
cal=map(season,ext_dates,.progress = TRUE)

### We bind the result and extract the dates before the 16th april (end of the regular season)
dates=bind_rows(cal) %>%
  filter(Notes==""|is.na(Notes)) %>%
  select(-Notes) %>% 
  mutate(fix_date=mdy(Date)) %>% 
  filter(fix_date<ymd("2025-04-16")) %>% 
  mutate(fix_date=as.character(fix_date)) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  pull(fix_date)

### We write a function to read and extract data for each date
### Note we're using "Sys.sleep" in order to wait for the page to load completely
### The code can manage when the data is splitted on multiple pages or not

nba = function(x) {
  url=paste0("https://www.nba.com/stats/players/passing?DateFrom=",x,"&DateTo=",x,"&page=all&SeasonType=Regular%20Season")
  a = read_html_live(url)
  Sys.sleep(3)
  c = a %>% html_element('div[class*="Pagination_pageDropdown"] select') %>% length()
  if (c != 0) {
    a$press(css = 'div[class*="Pagination_pageDropdown"] select', key_code = 'ArrowUp')
    a$scroll_into_view(css = 'div[class*="FooterLegalSection_legalCopy"]')
  }
  Sys.sleep(3)
  temp = a %>% html_element(css = 'table[class*="Crom_table"]') %>% html_table() %>%
    setNames(colnames) %>%
    select(-dummy) %>%
    mutate(date = x, .before = 1)
  a$session$close()
  rm(a)
  gc()
  return(temp)
}

### We apply the function to each date and bind the results
out=map(dates,possibly(nba,tibble(date=NA_character_)),.progress = TRUE)
fin=bind_rows(out)

### We can check if all dates have been correctly scraped with
setdiff(dates,fin$date)

### If there's some missing data, we rerun the code for these specific dates
check_dates=setdiff(dates,fin$date)
out_2=map(check_dates,possibly(nba,tibble(date=NA_character_)),.progress = TRUE)
fix=bind_rows(out_2)

### We combine the second table with the first one to have a complete dataset
fix$date[is.na(fix$date)]<-setdiff(check_dates,fix$date)
test=fin %>% filter(!is.na(PLAYER)) %>% bind_rows(fix) %>% arrange(date)

### We check if there's still missing data with
test %>% filter(is.na(PLAYER))

Any help would be much appreciated thank you!
